# Dump wallet with only watch-only addresses

Tags: wallet, watch-only

I have two wallets on a bitcoind node that consist entirely of watch-only addresses I have added with `importaddress` over time. I now want to merge these two wallets into one.

My initial thought was to do `dumpwallet` and `importwallet`, but the file generated with `dumpwallet` does not contain the watch-only addresses.

How would one go about merging two wallets into a single one and maintaining all the address labels?